# VGA laptop port to HDMI Monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

So, I received this laptop from my work, and I have 2 HDMI monitors that I want to connect to. The problem is that, the laptop has only 1x HDMI port and 1x VGA. The HDMI port works fine, but if I try to connect the VGA port with a VGA cable and use a connector to transition to HDMI (VGA female to HDMI male), the laptop detects the third monitor and display it in "Display settings", however there is no image. Is it even possible to get an image from such type of transition and what do you think the problem can be ?

Comment: Are you sure the adapter is one that converts analog signal to digital signal?

Comment: Are you sure it's a VGA to HDMI adaptor, not an HDMI to VGA? Link to your source might help.

Comment: What is the laptop model? Not all laptops actually support using the HDMI and VGA at the same time, and limit themselves to only two monitors. (internal and external)